# openFeatureForm in PyQGIS Standalone Application

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, standalone

I am trying to implement a desktop application with PyQGIS 3. When I try to use `openFeatureForm` to display the data of the selected layer object it shows an error, however when I use this code in the Python Console in QGIS it works correctly.

How can I use it for the application I'm doing outside of QGIS?

```py
def info(self):
    self.vlayer = QgsVectorLayer('provincias.shp', "Provincias", "ogr")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.vlayer)
    layer = self.vlayer
    features = layer.getFeatures()
    feat = layer.getFeature(2)
    iface.openFeatureForm(layer, feat, True)
```

This is the console error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/proyectos/catastroesp/catastro.py", line 111, in info
    iface.openFeatureForm(layer, feat, True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'openFeatureForm'
```

Answer (score 2):

`iface` is predefined variable in QGIS. It is defined while QGIS starts and refers to QGIS interface. That means you can use `iface` only within QGIS.

If you would like to show a feature form as in QGIS, you need to design it for your standalone application.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's why it works fine on the console. I will have to design the forms

Comment: It is easy to make a simple form containing only attribute names and its values for feature.